# storing a mirror of IMAP/pop3 folder/inbox in a local DB, what choices are there?

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I have a email inbox that will soon hit 4 million messages, I have an app that runs different policies over the inbox to associate emails with each other much like the conversation plugin for Thunderbird.
It is now becoming impossible to do so and I have been thinking about moving the emails to a DB as they come in and process them there and then, the processor needs to access the body and header. What database engine is best for this task mysql,postgre,etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try [DBMail](http://dbmail.org/) as local IMAP storage, and either use any of various IMAP syncing solutions or regular SMTP forwarding to get the mail in there.

Comment: I dont know much about DBMail my self, but it seems like to use this I have to replace everything on the server by DBMail and let it handle everything from user authentication to mail storage, although DBMail seems attractive, I was more looking for a mirror rather than replacement, is thatpossible?

Comment: Hence the suggestion to use IMAP synching.

Comment: I have no idea what :" IMAP syncing solutions" Are :(

Comment: http://freesoftware.zona-m.net/dbmail-a-great-open-source-email-system-especially-for-lampmysql-administrators/    seems like dbmail is not an option for what I need